# Unable to call python script from PHP

Tags: php, python-2.7

I want to call python script from php file, both files are placed in same directory

Here is my PHP code:-

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("/home/vyclean06/Desktop/trlNerr/boobank/Paypal.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

after executing this code got following error

`sh: 1: /home/vyclean06/Desktop/trlNerr/boobank/Paypal.py: Permission denied`

What went wrong in my code

Comment: Well quiet obviously, the php script / web user doesn't have permissions to access / execute the python script.

Comment: I want to add that my python files are in structure of classes and object format

Answer (score 0):

check if paypal.py associated to the same user(apache i guess).
if not, try to run(ubuntu):

```
chown www-data:www-data Paypal.py
```

centos

```
chown -R apache.apache Paypal.py
```

if yes, make it executable with

```
chmod +x Paypal.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell exec() or execshellcmd() to run the python script as a specific user without having to alter any permissions on it in advance. If you know the user that has permission to run that file you can do something like the following. This example is saying that the script should be run as the user "root" regardless of what user PHP is using.

```
exec("sudo -u root -S /home/vyclean06/Desktop/trlNerr/boobank/Paypal.py");
```

Or like some of the comments suggest, check what permissions are against it and ensure the "apache" user (or whatever user PHP runs as) has the right permissions.

Given you are using exec you can find out the PHP user by doing:

```
exec("whoami");
```